# Using something like auto for initialization

Tags: c++, std

Does something exist in the standard library or language that allows me to avoid having to repeat myself in the following situation?  In one case I have to duplicate the type name.  In the other, I duplicate the left side.  `auto` is very helpful when doing initialization, but assignment doesn't have such an elegant solution.

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> howdy;
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> there;
howdy = std::map<std::string, std::string>{there.begin(), there.end())};
howdy = decltype(howdy){there.begin(), there.end())};
```

Something like this does the trick but I would like know if something already exists.

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void assign(T& t, Args&&... args)
{
    t = T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> howdy;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> there;
    assign(howdy, there.begin(), there.end());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the type! :)

```
howdy = {there.begin(), there.end()};
```

This is called copy-list-initialization, you can read more about it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). It uses aggregate initialization if possible, or calls the appropriate non-explicit constructor to construct the object.

Comment: Give me a minute to accept your answer. I can't answer is less that 10 apparently.  LOL.